# Convert object to byte

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, byte

I want to convert an object, to a byte with silverlight.

So, first I found this : [convert object(i.e any object like person, employee) to byte[] in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281195/convert-objecti-e-any-object-like-person-employee-to-byte-in-silverlight)

But this is not working(any of the answers), the dll proto seems not to be good.

Plus, i tried this:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Address));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, address);
            }

            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

But I got a result in the byte.

What I receive is an object `byte[0]` , and I just want to verify his lenght is 0 or more.
I cannot do tihs with an `object`, and that's why I tried to convert it. But the byte in result is different from `byte[0]`

How can I do what I want? Just a comparison to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading again your question, if the object is already a `byte[]` simply cast it:

```
object yourObject = xxx();
byte[] data = (byte[])yourObject;
bool hasData = data != null && data.Length > 0;
```

Comment: I read that it can happened trouble when just cast? Is that true or not?

Comment: The object must be of type `byte[]` or `null` for the cast to works. If you can't guarantee that, you can check the data type using `is` keyword or the `as` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you like there is also the `MemoryStream` object which convert `object` to `byte[]` and `byte[]` to `object`

Comment: This was my first answer, but after reading again the question, I understood that the OP did not want to deserialize the data, but simply be able to check if there is data in a byte array, which is declared as object.

Comment: true. just re-read again. question was confusing at first. vote on Steve answer